# Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context Using Paper Onboarding

Tags: swift, swift5, xcode12

I am trying to use paper onboarding for my application but I am always getting the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". I'm using Xcode 12. There's no error anywhere else except on the return part of the function "func onboardingItemsCount". I am fairly new to xcode so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Here's part of the code:

```
func onboardingItemsCount() -> Int {
    return 3
}

func onboardingItem(at index: Int) -> OnboardingItemInfo {
    
    let backgroundColorOne = UIColor(red: 217/255, green: 72/255, blue: 89/255, alpha: 1)
    let backgroundColorTwo = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 166/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1)
    let backgroundColorThree = UIColor(red: 168/255, green: 200/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 1)
    
    let titleFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 24)!
    let descriptionFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18)

    return [
        
         OnboardingItemInfo(informationImage: "image_1",
                                       title: "Healthy + Food",
                                 description: "Quickly search and add healthy foods",
                                    pageIcon: "",
                                       color: backgroundColorOne,
                                  titleColor: UIColor.white,
                            descriptionColor: UIColor.white,
                                   titleFont: titleFont,
                             descriptionFont: descriptionFont),
                                
        
         OnboardingItemInfo(informationImage: "image_2",
                                        title: "Healthy + Cart",
                                  description: "Add items to your cart",
                                     pageIcon: "",
                                        color: backgroundColorTwo,
                                   titleColor: UIColor.white,
                             descriptionColor: UIColor.white,
                                    titleFont: titleFont,
                              descriptionFont: descriptionFont),
        
        OnboardingItemInfo(informationImage: "image_3",
                                     title: "Healthy + Delivery",
                               description: "View Markets in your area",
                                  pageIcon: "",
                                     color: backgroundColorThree,
                                titleColor: UIColor.white,
                          descriptionColor: UIColor.white,
                                 titleFont: titleFont,
                           descriptionFont: descriptionFont)

     ] [index]            (Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context)
    
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try this

```
let descriptionFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18)!
```

instead of

```
let descriptionFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18)
```